# How to clear the Tabs in a TabHost of Android?

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to reset the tabs in a Tabhost of Android platform and every time I try to do I get some issue or other.

Below is  the code which I use:

```
  if(reset)
  {
     tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
     //tabHost.clearAllTabs();
     tabHost.getTabWidget().removeAllViews();
  }
```

I get the following exception:

> e01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:557)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViews(ViewGroup.java:2146)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at com.t.android.m.setupTabs(CAndroidUI.java:97)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at com.t.android.m.DoRegistrationNotification(CAndroidUI.java:175)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at com.t.android.m.Handler$2.handleQchatServiceEvent(QServiceHandler.java:236)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at com.t.android.m.LStub.onTransact(ServiceCallback.java:62)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:287)
>   01-06 07:31:48.287: WARN/System.err(1581):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

Could some one give me a clue on what's happening?

Comment: Any luck on this yet? Looks like you are calling the tabhost from another thread than the UI thread that created the tabhost. Where is this code located? In your activity?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're currently calling that piece of code from another thread.

Also, if your variable naming convention is ok, you're currently removing the views of TabHost and not the content of the tabs instead ( i'm not sure if this is what you want )